# How to validate OAuth token in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Cloud gateway application which currently supports "HTTP basic auth". I'm planning to use OAuth 2.0 with Keycloak as the provider. I have started by adding required packages (listed below).

```
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client"
```

I'm new to this and want to support the following things.

1. Register clients dynamically to Keycloak
2. Validate the current request token with Keycloak to allow/ deny the request

My `SecurityConfig.java` is as given below.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().permitAll())
                .oauth2Client();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClientHttpRoutingFilter webClientHttpRoutingFilter(
            @Qualifier("webClient") WebClient webClient,
            ObjectProvider<List<HttpHeadersFilter>> headerFilters) {

        return new WebClientHttpRoutingFilter(webClient, headerFilters);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(
            @Qualifier("reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager")
                    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager) {

        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager);

        oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);

        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("keycloak");

        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .clientCredentials()
                        .build();

        DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);

        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want that a Keycloak authorization server can ensure that your spring boot app requires such authorization. Is that correct? If it is that you can use a Keycloak docker image locally, create an app on it and use its access token.

Comment: I cannot instantiate you class due to the error `Error creating bean with name 'securityWebFilterChain' defined in class path resource [SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityWebFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: clientRegistrationRepository cannot be null`. Maybe you post what is missing and I can work on your problem...

Comment: I wanna know how to register clients dynamically. Most importantly this configuration is done in Spring Cloud Gateway application